# Notifying message (Fade Out ) is disappearing instantly due to page reload behvaiour

Tags: jquery

I am doing a ajax call and  notifying the User as shown below

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var response = true ;
        if(response)
        {
$(".success").html('<strong>Success!</strong>Value Updated Successfully  !!!').fadeIn(800).delay(1500).fadeOut(800);        
window.location.reload();
        }
});
```

The problem is that the notfying message is disapperaing instantly

Is it possible to reload the page only after the fadeOut has been completed successfully

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/430/

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
$(".success").html('<strong>Success!</strong>Value Updated Successfully  !!!').fadeIn(800).delay(1500).fadeOut(800);        
window.location.reload();
```

to

```
$(".success").html('<strong>Success!</strong>Value Updated Successfully  !!!').fadeIn(800).delay(1500).fadeOut(800, function () {        
    window.location.reload();
});
```

In the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) you can find your case:

> `.fadeOut([duration], [complete])`
>
> **complete**
>
> A function to call once the animation is complete (...)

This is called a "callback function". You'll find it's being used a lot in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

[.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) has a callback function so you change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var response = true;
    if (response) {
        $(".success").html('<strong>Success!</strong>Value Updated Successfully  !!!').fadeIn(800).delay(1500).fadeOut(800, function () {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fadeOut` function as well as the [other `fade` animation functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/), provides a callback that is triggered when the animation is finished.

Here is an example that was take from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) -

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

So for your case, using this callback would look something like this -

```
$(".success").html(...).fadeIn(800).delay(1500).fadeOut(800, function() {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

---

Since the action you want to take is actually calling an existing function, you can pass the `window.location.reload` function as the callback itself to allow your code to be a little cleaner -

```
...fadeOut(800, window.location.reload);
```

You only need to define your own callback function if there are more actions that you want to perform.